# My Windows 10 HP laptop loads for a long time while installing Windows 10 using a bootable Pen drive

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, bootable-media

When **I performed a DST Check using HP PC Hardware Diagnostic UEFI and it failed**, so I thought to **reinstall Windows 10 using a bootable Pen Drive and made correct changes in BIOS** but **HP logo and those dots spinning there for a long time.** How do I fix this issue ?

Comment: What hardware did it test? What were the error codes for each?

Answer (score 0):

> DST Check using HP PC Hardware Diagnostic UEFI and it failed...

Your hard drive is failing and it needs to be replaced.

See your local computer store or ask HP Support.

You need to replace it sooner rather than later.

Comment: I don't think there is any hardware problem. It all happened after failed windows 10 factory reset

Comment: The error says hardware fault and the machine is slow as a result

Comment: Also, Windows 10 on good hardware is fast, not slow.

Comment: when I was using Windows 10 after the failed reset, I could use C drive but I couldn't shrink it and it was not shown in disk defragmenter. Then I used a already downloaded ISO file from media creation tool to reinstall Windows 10 but at the last step it said that the ISO is corrupt and after that whenever I turn on Windows if open Windows Boot Manager and there are only two options (1) Windows Setup Rollback (2) Windows 10 and when I select any of the two options the screen goes black. Even when I am booting with a bootable USB, HP logo shows and the dots mover around for a long time.

Comment: You have an error that says there is a hardware error and that is probably why.